# c# list search results in listbox

Tags: c#, search

I need to list results in a listbox when user clicks on Search Button based on Last Name or based on Program. The results will be read from an external access file (connection is successful).

I have defined:

```
Name of List Box: lstResultListBox
Name of Text Box: LastNameProgramTextBox
Name of Search Button: SearchButton
Radio button 1: byLastNameRadioButton
Radio button 2: byProgramRadioButton
Clear Button: ClearButton
```

I've not provided the database table here.

Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'StudentsDataSet.Student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.studentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.StudentsDataSet.Student);
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var students =
        from s in this.StudentsDataSet.Student
        where s.LastName == LastNameProgramTextBox.Text
        where s.ProgramName == LastNameProgramTextBox.Text
        select s;
        foreach (var s in students)
        {
            lstResultListBox.Items.Add(s.LastName + ", " + s.FirstName);
        }
    }

    private void lstResultListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LastNameProgramTextBox.Text = lstResultListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

I am unable to get the search or clear buttons to work! I tried the Search_Click and the SelectedIndexChanged but I can't figure out what I am missing. This is the first time I do Search in C# Windows Forms.
I have properly defined the names of the ListBox, TextBox, Search Button, Clear Button and Radio Buttons.

[ScreenShot of Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHsAw.png)

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: since you have radio buttons for lastName and program, your search should have only one where criteria based on the radio button selected. Also, are you doing a full text search?

Comment: Have you set click listeners on button in Properties? Scroll to "click" in [this button description](https://www.dotnetperls.com/button)